# Python - youtube-dl.utils.DownloadError: ERROR: audio conversion failed: file: mp3 invalid argument

Tags: python, ffmpeg, youtube-dl, lame

`youtube-dl.utils.DownloadError: ERROR: audio conversion failed: file: mp3 invalid argument`

The above error appears with following parameters, running youtube-dl on Python 3.6 on Windows 7, FFmpeg and libmp3lame installed.

```
ydl_opts = {                                                
"format": "bestaudio/best",
"extractaudio": True,
"outtmpl": fetch_name + "%(ext)s",
"noplaylist": True,
"nocheckcertificate": True,
"postprocessors": [{
    "key": "FFmpegExtractAudio",
    "preferredcodec": "mp3",
    "preferredquality": "192",
}],
"progress_hooks": [hook]
}
```

fetch_name is for example `C:\Path\File`. `[hook]` just displays download messages.
I've searched here and on internet but can't find this error.

Comment: [mcve] would be helpful for diagnosis.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a "." to the end of the outtmpl. The error magically goes away.

I haven't checked, but I suspect this is an error with youtube-dl, where it expects a file extension to replace.

I don't know if bumping a dead question is frowned upon in here, but I thought I'd give light to this, since I was being bothered with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
options={
        'writethumbnail':True,
        'format':'bestaudio/best',
        'keepvideo':False,
        'outtmpl.':filename,
        'postprocessors':[{'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
            'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
            'preferredquality': '192'},
            {'key': 'EmbedThumbnail',},]
    }
```

This piece of script might help you. It worked for me very well.

Answer (score -1):

I traced back the arguments you have in your code and found this [file](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/054b99a33079dcc4755e46aaf588424b4bb12020/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py#L201), which in turn traces back to the list of [postprocessors](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/054b99a33079dcc4755e46aaf588424b4bb12020/youtube_dl/postprocessor/__init__.py#L29).

As you can see the post processor is named `FFmpegExtractAudioPP` where as you have used `FFmpegExtractAudio`. May be this is where you are getting it wrong.

Comment: as you can see in [the source of how the CLI option `-x` is handled by youtube-dl itself](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/2791e80b60e1ca1c36b83ca93be35e7e5418a1c3/youtube_dl/__init__.py#L259), the postprocessor's `key` has no `PP` at the end.